# convergence of $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

How do I check convergence/ uniform convergence of $\sum\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$.

Also for series $\sum \sin \left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$, can I use that $\sin x \leq x$?

Comment: $\sin x \leq x$ is false when $x<0$. Just plot the two graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first series we have a point-wise convergence on the interval $(-1,1)$ since for $-1<x<1$ we have
$$\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\sim_\infty x^n$$
and the geometric series $\sum_n x^n$ is convergent. There's not a unifrom convergence on this interval because the limit
$$\lim_{x\pm1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$$
doesn't exist.

For the second series we have
$$\sin\left(\frac x{n^2}\right)\sim_\infty \frac x{n^2}$$
and the Riemann series is convergent. There's not a uniform convergence on $\Bbb R$
because the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac1n\right)$$
is divergent.

Comment: For the ist series what about when $|x|\geq1$

Comment: It's divergent. Do you see why?

Comment: Because $x^n$ is divergent for that range. And how the divergence of $\sum \sin (\frac 1n$ used to prove not uniform convergence?

Comment: Not quite: for $|x|\ge1$ the general term of the series doesn't converge to $0$.For the second series replace $x$ by $n$ in the given sum.